# Problem on creating new VCL Froms Applcation

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

When I want to create new VCL Forms application on Delphi XE7 then show me '10' is not a valid identifier. Please help me to solve this problem

[image]

Comment: Can you describe exact what you did when you got this error ? Was there another project open when you tried to create a new application ? Give us some more info please

Comment: I can't remember, but i close all projects and try to create new VCL Forms Application but it's not working. Nevertheless i can create Multi Device Application forms (only Tabbed with Navigation)

Comment: Seems it could be an error from the one of installed packages. Try to disable them one by one, excepting system packages.